# Spring: override parent bean

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to override/replace parent abstract bean?

E.G:
1st xml:

```
<bean id="inheritedTestBean" abstract="true" class="org.springframework.beans.TestBean">
</bean>

<bean id="inheritsWithDifferentClass" class="org.springframework.beans.DerivedTestBean" parent="inheritedTestBean">
</bean>
```

2nd xml

```
<bean id="inheritedTestBean2" abstract="true" class="org.springframework.beans.TestBean2">
</bean>
<alias name="inheritedTestBean2" alias="inheritedTestBean" />
```

TestBean2 inherits TestBean.

Answer (score 1):

Any given Spring context can only have one bean for any given id or name. In the case of the XML id attribute, this is enforced by the schema validation. In the case of the name attribute, this is enforced by Spring's logic.

However, if a context is constructed from two different XML descriptor files, and an id is used by both files, then one will "override" the other. The exact behaviour depends on the ordering of the files when they get loaded by the context.

So while it's possible, it's not recommended. It's error-prone and fragile, and you'll get no help from Spring if you change the ID of one but not the other.

Comment: In your first called XML configuration file :

 <bean id="myBeanId" class="com.blabla">
       <property name="myList" ref="myList"/>
   </bean>

   <util:list id="myList">
       <value>3</value>
       <value>4</value>
   </util:list>In your second called XML configuration file   <util:list id="myList">
       <value>6</value>
   </util:list>

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could do this, it would be very confusing. There is the `@Primary` annotation, you can take a look at that. Or you could take a look at spring profiles, so you have a default bean implementation, and then every other profile there is a different implementation for your abstract class.